# Call function on load with setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, setinterval

I have a function `update()` that is called at 5 second intervals:

```
setInterval(function() {
    update();
}, 5000);
```

My objective, however, is to call the function immediately *on load* and then every 5 seconds after that.  How would one achieve this in javascript or jQuery ?

Comment: `window.onload = function() { update(); setInterval(update, 5000); };`

Comment: `window.addEventListener('load', update)` would trigger it on load. Why worry is the interval triggers it slightly sooner than 5 secs after? Otherwise, write a load function that calls update and sets the interval and attach it to the load events as before.

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like this.

Simply call update immediately, then add your timeout callback after that.

```
update();
setInterval(update, 5000);
```

Comment: it's `setInterval` not `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
update();
setInterval(update, 5000);
```

This would call `update()` immediately.

If by "on load" you mean you want to wait until the page is loaded, you can do this in jQuery (since you asked about jQuery):

```
$(function () {
    update();
    setInterval(update, 5000);
});
```